# How to download the edu.mit.sketch.geom libraries

Tags: java, download, geometry, package

On the Java API, I see references to packages named "edu.mit.sketch.geom." I'm looking for some advanced geometry libraries (mainly collision interpretation), and after a brief overview of the methods contained the package is looking really good, and I'd like to try it out.

However, I can't find any downloads. It doesn't appear to be in the standard Java library, and I'd like to package it as a jar in my project, but a few Google searches return references to the package but no download.

Does anyone know where I can get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Google'd around a bit and the only place I could find what looks like the toolkit you want was on the [handouts page of the 6.893 course at MIT](http://csg.csail.mit.edu/6.893/handouts.html): [direct link](http://csg.csail.mit.edu/6.893/Handouts/toolkit.zip); there doesn't seem to be a project site, at least, not a public one.